# Can not start alpha/internal android testing before publishing app as production version in Play Store

Tags: android, testing, google-play, google-play-console

yesterday we are created a new app in Google Play Console. Then we upload a new release APK into Alpha-Track, added emails for test-group and waiting already more then 24h. Nothing happen. We can't see any opt-in link for testing...

Today early morning I created a new "internal"-track for testing (in google docs stay that the APK-file will be available for testing after 10-15 minutest after publishing)...

We waiting already many hours and nothing happen...

What we did wrong or maybe something missed in configuration to start testing before publishing app in real store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first upload of an APK or App Bundle to the Play Console may take a bit longer to go through validation. It's not uncommon to have to wait 48 hours or more.

The internal app sharing indeed advertises the app being available within minutes, but that's only after having successfully passed the first validation. Once your app is available in one track, then every future uploads to internal app sharing should effectively be available within seconds or minutes.

Comment: it was more then 3 days... but now the app is available for testing! thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

In the "Manage Testers" section of the "Internal test" track, there should be an "Opt-in URL", see screenshot below (this is just a portion of the URL, usually a number appended to the end):

[image: Opt-in URL portion]

You will need to send this URL to any of the email addresses of testers you'd like to test the app, for them to be able to see the app updates from the Internal Test track.

Comment: Hallo @jsmyth886 this is not available now... this is what we need exactly.

Comment: @JarvisAbraveya could you upload a screenshot (removing anything business related or sensitive) of Google Play Console -> App Releases -> Internal Test -> Manage Testers screen. This will greatly help diagnosing your issue